# What is the hit rate of the cache when executing this code?

Tags: memory-management, mips, caching

C++ code:

```
int main()
{
short int arr[4][4];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
  {
    arr[i][j] = i+j;
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

Is there going to be a difference in hit time if it is loading data from arrays or storing data into array. For example for `arr[i][j] = i+j;` and `a = arr[i][j];` ?

Also what is difference in hit time if it is `arr[j][i] = i+j;`

Comment: Since the array is quite short and cache is often done in blocks afaik, isn't it likely that the entire array gets cached, so every access after the first is a hit?

Comment: Yes, is it going to be the same for arr[j][i] = i+j ?

Comment: I am not really seeing any reason for it to be different

Comment: Okay, so when we are storing the data to the array, the hit time for both arr[j][i] and arr[i][j] would be same ? But when we are loading the data from the array. It should be different

Comment: If the entire array is cached, by that i mean the block containing the entire array is brought into cache on the first access, then all subsequent access should take the same time.

Comment: If we are saying that each entry of the array is cached individually when accessed, then hit time and hit rate should be dependent upon the cache size and caching policy

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuVmdDd3eGE&t=66s

Answer (score 1):

Your program will most likely crash because you access non-existing array elements.